# Get actual line number where curser is JavaFX with RichTextFX

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

Is there a function in RichTextFX to get the actual line number where the curser?

Github: [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/tree/master/richtextfx/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the index of the caret ("cursor") with

```
int offset = textArea.getCaretPosition();
```

and then convert to a `TwoDimensional.Position` with

```
Position pos = textArea.offsetToPosition(offset);
```

From there, `pos.getMajor()` is the paragraph (line) number (and `pos.getMinor()` is the index of the caret within the line).

Comment: Do you mean textArea.getCaretColumn()?

Also, upvoted because you got me 99% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current paragraph index or line number with:

```
codeArea.getCaretSelectionBind().getParagraphIndex();
```